# Unable to pass values from one js file to another js file protractor e2e testing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, pageobjects

Below is the code where I am unable to return value from GenericUtil.js to homepage.js

I am trying to implement Page objects along with Hybrid driven framework.

```
//GenericUtil.js:

var blnFlag;
GenericUtilities = function(){
    this.objClick = function(objLocator){
        element.all(objLocator).then(function(items) {
            if (items.length == 1) {
                element(objLocator).click();
                blnFlag='True';
                console.log("Inside if" + blnFlag);
            }
            else {
                blnFlag='False';
                console.log("inside else" + blnFlag);
            };
        });
        return blnFlag;
    };
};
module.exports = new GenericUtilities();

//home_page.js:

var blnFlag;
var gu = require("../GenericUtilities/GenericUtil.js");
var home_page = function(){
    this.clickContinue = function(){
        blnFlag = gu.objClick(home_page_obj.btnContinue);
        console.log("After return" + blnFlag );
    };
};
module.exports = new home_page();

//The value is being returned as undefined.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
//GenericUtil.js:
var blnFlag,
    GenericUtilities = function(){
       this.objClick = function(objLocator){
           element.all(objLocator).then(function(items) {
               if (items.length == 1) {
                   element(objLocator).click();
                   blnFlag='True';
                   console.log("Inside if" + blnFlag);
               }
               else {
                   blnFlag='False';
                   console.log("inside else" + blnFlag);
               };
           });
           return blnFlag;
       };
   };


module.exports = GenericUtilities;

//home_page.js:

var blnFlag,
    GenericUtilities = require("../GenericUtilities/GenericUtil.js"),
    gu = new GenericUtilities(),
    home_page = function(){
        this.clickContinue = function(){
           blnFlag = gu.objClick(home_page_obj.btnContinue);
           console.log("After return" + blnFlag );
        };
    };



module.exports = new home_page();

//The value is being returned as undefined.
```

EDIT: this is what i have done then

```
//GenericUtil.js:
var GenericUtilities = function () {
   this.bnlFlag = 'False';
   this.action = function () {
       this.bnlFlag = 'True';
   };
};

module.exports = new GenericUtilities();


//home_page.js:
var bnlFlag,
    gu = require("./generic.js"),
    home_page = function(){
        this.clickContinue = function(){
            bnlFlag = gu.bnlFlag;
            console.log("Before return " + bnlFlag );
            gu.action();
            bnlFlag = gu.bnlFlag;
            console.log("After return " + bnlFlag );
        };
    };

module.exports = new home_page();

// test in an other file
var home = require('./home.js');
home.clickContinue();
```

And this is working :

```
Before return False
After return True
```

Comment: No luck. It still returns undefined.I want to return blnFlag value from GenericUtilities.js to home_page.js.

Comment: But if you see the code I have written in objClick function it is different. In objClick function I am trying to validate the count of elements and if the count is 1 and needs to perform some action over it and should return true else it should return false. I believe .then(function.........) is asynchronous function call and it is not allowing to return the value. Please suggest me.